# Антоним слова "грех"

Tags: антонимы

Задался вопросом: а какой антоним у слова "грех"? Словарь предложил мне "добродетель", но добродетель - это все-таки качество, а грех - скорее, поступок. То есть, грех может быть и явлением, тогда да, добродетель. Но, если все-таки поступок, то как? "Доброе дело"? Но это как-то мелко по сравнению с грехом. Благодеяние? Тоже не совсем то - оно, скорее, указывает, что сделал благо для кого-то, грех же, прежде всего, направлен против собственной души.
Какие будут идеи?

Comment: Святитель Тихон Задонский дает такое определение: «Добродетель есть всякое слово, дело и помышление, согласное с законом Божиим»[1]. Если грех - поступок, деяние против законов Бога, то добродетель - согласное с Богом деяние. Почему не антоним? В каких-то значениях грех и порок - синонимы, а порок и добродетель - антонимы, слова-то многозначны. Много раз видела и слышала:  "Грех и добродетель - стороны одной медали". Нормально сочетаются понятия.

Answer (score 6):

Есть такое толкование слова *грех*, как *промах*.

Подобно тому, как *погрешность* (например, в измерениях, в контрольно-измерительных приборах) -- это отклонение от того, как должно быть в идеале, в эталоне. Неточность. Некоторая неправильность, в той или иной степени. Кстати, *точно* - это по-хорватски *исто*. В русском есть выражение "истово молиться", к примеру.

Противоположное у славян издавна называлось, в тех или иных вариантах, - ПРАВильный ПУТЬ. Т.е. самые разные слова с корнем ПРАВ- и ПУТ-.

И наоборот. Непутёвая, беспутная, распутная девка - отклонилась с пути. Блуд и (нецензурное последние несколько столетий) бл*дь (извините), заблудшие души -- тоже намёк на то, что потеряна ПРАВильная дорога в жизни.

Противоположность греху, могу предположить, это **праведность** или **праведное дело**. Это и есть суть моего ответа.

Можно было бы ещё написать *"правое дело"*, но не знаю подойдёт ли вам по смыслу. *Изначально* выражение хорошее, но много в агитации использовалось. Но в общем-то почти все слова, предложенные в этой теме имеют пафосное звучание. Тема такая!

- - - 

**P.S.** Ещё пару слов о полузабытом теперь смысле, что грех - это промах. Для того, чтобы автору темы было лучше подобрать нужные по смыслу слова. Постараюсь коротко, чтобы не превратить ответ в обширную проповедь или философскую статью, а то тема способствует! :-)

Грех не синоним слова табу. И не синоним запретного удовольствия, как некоторые могут предполагать. У арабов есть слово "харам" - что значит *запрет* (для того, что делать не положено).

Так вот грех - это не просто нарушение запрета. Это неПРАВильное деяние, о котором раньше или позже придётся **пожалеть**! Из разряда поступков, к которым хочется вернуться назад в машине времени и всё переделать ПРАВильно. Важный момент - РАДости от этого нет! А вот тоска, депрессия, как правило будут.

Answer (score 5):

Благодеяние - как минимум частичный антоним.
Точных и полных антонимов, видимо, нет.

> > > Безгрешность, непогрешимость.

"Справка" неточна, "грех" - поступок, имеющий некоторую моральную оценку. Антонимом должно служить слово, обозначающее поступок с противоположной моральной оценкой, а не отсутствие такового. "Справка" дает антонимы скорее для слов "греховность", "грешность".

Тут надо иметь в виду, что само слово "грех" в современном языке несколько изменило значение. Но если оставаться в рамках церковного понимания (поступок нарушающий установленные моральные правила для христианина), то антонимом будет **"подвиг"** в аналогичном, церковном понимании (деяние по славу Христа или веры).

Тему подняли, решил добавить, а то уже второй участник пытается протащить "саваб" как **точный** антоним греху.

Вот точная формулировка антонима: "благовидном поступке, заслуживающем вознаграждения или похвалы".
Это не совсем "саваб" в исламском понимании, хотя и близко. Но все равно дальше, чем наш христианский **"подвиг"** в его исконном понимании.

Comment: @behemothus, с вами соглашусь, что благодеяние как минимум частичный синоним. В русском языке вообще как таковой антоним к слову грех отсутствует. Благодеяние( как справедливо отметил автор одной статьи в интернете), добродетель - это все лишь слова описывающие жизненные позиции, поступки и убеждения, которые делают нас духовнее, чище, а вот объединяющего их слова нет.Можно привести еще один условный антоним - Закон (в онтологическом смысле).

Comment: . Антонимом "подвига" я бы назвал преступление. Но уж никак не грех. Поэтому  я согласен с справкой. Наиболее оптимальный вариант " безгрешность, непогрешимость". Т.е. отсутствие как такого поступка, не совершение такого поступка. Опять-таки, как я отметил выше, это оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Я сказал, что оба слова несколько изменило значение.
Подвиг в христианском понимании - деяние во славу Христа или веры.
"Преступление" - довольно слабый антоним даже в современном понимании. Субъективно, конечно, но хорошим антонимом к подвигу было бы слово означающее **позорный** поступок, не обязательно **преступный**.

Answer (score 4):

"Благодеяние" вы зря отбросили. Это слово предполагает под собой религиозную мораль, с абсолютными величинами добра и зла, где на одной стороне будет добрый поступок - благодеяние, а на другой злой - грех. Я, являясь атеистом и сторонником относительности добра и зла, подобные слова употреблять не буду.

Так как многие религии, в том числе и православие, имеют постулат об изначальной греховности человека (первородный грех), то в некоторых контекстах, возможен такой антоним как *искупление*.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Безгрешность, непогрешимость.

Answer (score 1):

ГРЕХ - путь изогнутый, искривленный (согласно этимологии), также: тьма, заблуждение, путаница, ошибка, искушение темных сил.

АНТОНИМЫ - праведный путь, также: свет, правда, истина,

Соответственно: человек грешный и человек святой, праведный.

Answer (score 0):

Грех в Библии имеет одно значение - НЕПОСЛУШАНИЕ БОГУ. К Римлянам, 5:19. Ибо как непослушанием одного человека (то есть Адама) сделались многие грешными, так и послушанием одного (то есть Иисуса) сделались праведными многие.
(Из этого следует, грех - праведность.)

Comment: Неверно. В церковной тематике Вы, видимо, разбираетесь, а вот слова "антоним" не чувствуете. *Праведность* - антоним к ***греховности***. А грех и греховность - это совсем не одно и тоже.

Comment: Совершенно без претензий на толкование понятий греха и т. д. в христианстве - только с точки зрения языка и происхождения слов:  в исходном ветхозаветном языке семантика слова "грех" действительно "промах" или "отклонение". Промах при стрельбе. Акела промахнулся. Близкие по смыслу но не однокоренные слова: заблудший/ая, блудница - семантика "отклонение",  "потеря правильного пути".  Здесь же - технический термин "погрешность" - без какой-либо моральной нагрузки. В этом семантическом поле антоним "греха" - праведность, т. е. устойчивое систематическое следование правильному пути.

Answer (score 0):

В Исламе эта проблема решена точно: имеется слово саваб. См.: [http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/islam/677/Саваб](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/islam/677/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B1)

Comment: Неверно. Грех - это **поступок**. Антоним тоже должен быть поступком. **Саваб - это награда за праведную жизнь**. А не сама такая жизнь - и уж тем тем более **не поступок**. Вы запутались.

Comment: К тому же, при чем тут ислам? Вопрос чисто лингвистический,нельзя же богословский термин переносить на общее понятие? К тому же понятия "греха" не может быть полностью привязано к религии вообще, это вещь, как бы сказать... надрелигиозная. И Антоним выбирается из того же понятийного поля.

Comment: @Мимоходов, Вы думаете, понятие греха можно оторвать от религии?

Comment: @М_Г думаю, что контексте лингвистики - просто нужно. Но это даже не главное. К Мурада пироги с котятами получились даже в рамках религиозных воззрений. На примере. Есть грех  - есть подвиг (примерный антоним греха в христиансве). Подвижники (праведники) попадают в Рай. Это вознаграждение за подвиг, за "антоним греха". Но сам по себе Рай как антоним греха - это что-то из виртуальной вселенной. Вот в переложении на исламскую почву у Мурада так и получается.

Comment: Саваб - это не совсем рай, это как бы сказать... сама процедура вознаграждения салиха (праведника) или простого мусульманина, но уж к понятию "антоним греха" отношения имеет не больше, чем материнский капитал к зиею-искусителю.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, неверно искать поступок, противоположный греху. Позвольте привести аналогию. Какой поступок противоположен преступлению? Нет такого. Противоположность преступлению - законопослушность. Это не поступок, это образ жизни. Аналогично противоположость греху - жизнь без греха. В этой области и надо искать антонимы: **безгрешность, праведность, добро, добродетель**.

С некоторой натяжкой противоположностью греха можно считать его исправление - **покаяние**.

Еще пара слов. Это не тот случай, когда вы можете (1) ничего не делать, (2)совершать хорошие дела, либо (3) совершать плохие. Здесь у вас только два варианта: либо грешить, либо жить правильно (без греха), причем с точки зрения религии правильная жизнь подразумевает сознательные усилия (поступки), направленные на выполнение правил (заповедей), а отсутствие таковых поступков уже есть грех.

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке нет антома слова "грех". Он есть а арабском языке. "Саваб" - это арабский термин, означающий «награда». В частности, в контексте исламского мировоззрения под савабом понимается духовная заслуга или награда, получаемая от совершения добрых дел и благочестия.

Comment: Вы не находите, что противоречите себе? если слово "саваб" означает "награда", то это и есть антоним слову грех в русском?! Разумеется, вcе не так, "награда" не может считаться антонимом для "грех". Я не владею арабским, но подозреваю, что в контексте обсуждаемой темы, "награда " перевод крайне неудачный. Поверхностное знакомство с основами ислама позволяет мне предположить, что речь идет о ***"благовидном поступке, заслуживающем вознаграждения"***. Это, видимо и есть точный антоним к слову "грех", не имеющий соответствующего термина в русском.

Answer (score 0):

Антонимом к слову "грех" (негативный поступок) является слово "подвиг" (позитивный поступок).
А праведность - это "норма" (нейтральное положение).